# Derive formula for timezone on a datetime value

Tags: formula, datetime, timezone

Is it possible to create a text formula that can derive the datetime for a specific timezone? For example, if you have an activity record with a due date that you want to send a sms  text to the person that the activity is scheduled for (contact or lead) in their timezone. The timezone of this contact or lead is captured as a custom field on the event record. Since all datetimes are stored in Universal, I'd need to convert using the offset based on the timezone on the record for the due date of the record.

Comment: Yes, it's possible and your description of how it could be implemented is one possible approach. What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Are you wanting to present this field in the UI to a contextual user? If so, this cannot be done to arbitrarily show as the same time (I.e. "local time") for all users, regardless of their time zone and using their locale format, without custom UI. The timezone offset is not available in a formula unless you put it in a field.

Comment: No, I'm looking to generate a text value that would be used to pull into a SMS message. I think I can achieve what I'm wanting to do with an Apex method. I was looking at the DateTime methods and `format(dateFormatString, timezone)` method looks like it will work.